# How to check whether two arrays of objects are different, disregarding the order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

**Case 1**

```
let x =[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]
let y=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"3",name:"def"}]
```

isDifferent(x,y)  must return true.

**Case 2**

```
let a=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]
let b=[{_id:"2",name:"def"},{_id:"1",name:"abc"}]
```

isDifferent(a,b)  must return false.

**Case 3**

```
let p=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]
let q=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]
```

isDifferent(a,b)  must return false.

I tried using isMatch function of lodash

```
 isDifferent(arr1, arr2) {
        return !isMatch(arr1, arr2);
    }
```

**Case 1**  and **Case 3** works as expected. But in **Case 2**, the function returns true. Note that only the order of the objects in the array is interchanged.

I cannot check based on _id since the two arrays that I compare may not have _id at all.

```
let p=[{name:"abc",age:"2"},{name:"def",age:"2"}]
let q=[{name:"abc",age:"3"},{name:"def",age:"4"}]
```

The arrays could be like this. But what I can guarantee is the objects will have same properties in both arrays

Comment: A simple `JSON.stringify` test would seem to suffice here..?

Comment: Is lodash preferred? You could likely write a function to simply loop through the two objects' properties and test equality of one against the other. Since equality is transitive, you could just check element A against B, C, D, etc.

Comment: How so? Wouldn't stringifying and comparing the two arrays give false in case 2, where as I expect them to be true, since only the order is different?

Comment: I am already using lodash library for other purpose. Why write my own function if I can make use of the library? Isn't that why libraries exist?

Answer (score 1):

Use the isEuqual method provided by lodash as it performs a deep comparison between two values to determine if they are equivalent.

`_.isEqual(array1, array2);`

This method supports comparing arrays, array buffers, booleans, date objects, error objects, maps, numbers, Object objects, regexes, sets, strings, symbols, and typed arrays. Object objects are compared by their own, not inherited, enumerable properties. Functions and DOM nodes are compared by strict equality, i.e. ===.

Comment: Using the question's given test data, it seems your suggestion doesn't produce the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lodash#xorWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#xorWith) with [`lodash#isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEqual) as the comparator function to get an array of items that are different from argument `a` and `b`. We can infer that `a` and `b` are different based on the length of the resulting array.

```
function isDifferent(a, b) {
  return _.xorWith(a, b, _.isEqual).length > 0;
}
```

```js
let x =[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]
let y=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"3",name:"def"}];

let a=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}];
let b=[{_id:"2",name:"def"},{_id:"1",name:"abc"}];

let p=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}];
let q=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}];

console.log(isDifferent(x, y));

console.log(isDifferent(a, b));

console.log(isDifferent(p, q));

function isDifferent(a, b) {
  return _.xorWith(a, b, _.isEqual).length > 0;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll use `isEqual`() method.

```js
// False
    let x =[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]
    let y= [{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"3",name:"def"}]

    // true
    let a=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]
    let b=[{_id:"2",name:"def"},{_id:"1",name:"abc"}]

    //true
    let p=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]
    let q=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]

    function compare(a, b) {
    var key = Object.keys(a)[0];
    if (a[key] < b[key])
        return -1;
    if (a[key] > b[key])
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

function sortObject(o) {
    var sorted = {},
        key, a = [];
    for (key in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            a.push(key);
        }
    }
    a.sort();
    for (key = 0; key < a.length; key++) {
        sorted[a[key]] = o[a[key]];
    }
    return sorted;
}

function isEqual(array1, array2) {
    array1 = array1.map(x => sortObject(x)).sort(compare);
    array2 = array2.map(x => sortObject(x)).sort(compare);
    if (JSON.stringify(array1) === JSON.stringify(array2))
        return true;
    else return false;
}

console.log('Are x and y equal ==> ' + isEqual(x, y));
console.log('Are a and b equal ==> ' + isEqual(a, b));
console.log('Are p and q equal ==> ' + isEqual(p, q));
```

Comment: In this case, I understand. But I do not want to compare them using id, since I need the same function to work for all cases.

Comment: @Priya, I've changed the logic now. I am sorting Properties for the individual object and sorting array objects without specifying the particular property. I hope this code suits your need.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Here is a solution which works by sorting the arrays and then using `!_.isEqual` to compare them:

```js
let x=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]
let y=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"3",name:"def"}]

let a=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]
let b=[{_id:"2",name:"def"},{_id:"1",name:"abc"}]

let p=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]
let q=[{_id:"1",name:"abc"},{_id:"2",name:"def"}]


const isDifferent = (a, b) => {
  const sortArray = (arr) => _.sortBy(arr, ['id', 'name'])
  return !_.isEqual(sortArray(a), sortArray(b))
}

console.log('x & y: ', isDifferent(x,y))
console.log('a & b: ', isDifferent(a,b))
console.log('p & q: ', isDifferent(p,q))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```